# Excel Data export have small boxes with question marks

Tags: excel, apostrophe

I have exported one of my website data files as a CSV.. In the descriptions column, the apostrophes (') in the text have been replaced with "small boxes with question marks". Can you please advise how we replace these characters back to apostrophes.

Answer (score 0):

[Unicode issue with an HTML Title, question mark? 65533;](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3526965/191931)
Look at this previous question on stackoverflow, as it addresses your issue

see Jeff's article about Unicode http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/i-entity-unicode.html

which references this link and you should read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

and when you fix it>>>> http://www.cafepress.com/nucleartacos/317769

Answer (score 0):

When exporting to CSV files, it's not only important to understand encoding, as datatoo has already mentioned, but also quite a few other things, that might introduce data corruptions even stranger than the question marks you mention.

I've written an in depth article about it here: http://theonemanitdepartment.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/the-absolute-minimum-everyone-working-with-data-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-file-types-encoding-delimiters-and-data-types-no-excuses/