# How to save a file in NodeJS using a latin1 character encoding?

Tags: javascript, node.js, character-encoding, httprequest

This code downloads a sample latin1/ISO-8859-1 encoded file and saves it to disk. Open that file and you'll see the strange question mark characters �. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3527176/779159 explains it's because of the wrong encoding being applied, and latin1 should fix it.

```
const url = 'http://vancouver-webpages.com/multilingual/french.asis'
request.get(url, { encoding: null })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/file.txt', { defaultEncoding: 'latin1' }))
```

But using the `request` and `fs` modules, I can't get it to save in `latin1` encoding. How do I fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

Node v8.1.4 should support latin1 (aka 'binary') as one of its encodings for Buffer. I just tested your code and it actually works fine. I use Atom as my text editor and, initially, it thought it was 'UTF-8' so the question mark characters appeared. When I switched from UTF-8 to 'Auto-Detect', everything appeared okay. See the screenshot below.

[image: Windows 1252 Encoding on Atom]

Note how it says 'Windows 1252' for the encoding, but it works the same way if I selected 'ISO 8859-1'. So make sure that whatever editor you are using detects the character encoding correctly. It is not Node's fault!

By the way, an interesting thing to note, according to the [docs for Node v8.1.4](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffers_and_character_encodings), in one of the sections for Buffer:

> Today's browsers follow the WHATWG spec which aliases both 'latin1'
>   and ISO-8859-1 to **win-1252**. This means that while doing something like
>   http.get(), if the returned charset is one of those listed in the
>   WHATWG spec **it's possible that the server actually returned
>   win-1252-encoded data, and using 'latin1' encoding may incorrectly
>   decode the characters**.